# How to change image opacity and set innerhtml to blank at the same time

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make simple image game, in which player can see the images and we they start image opacity turn to 0 and they click the boxes to find the same pair of image.

In this code I wanted to change my image opacity back to 1 and set the innerhtml to blank when I click  restart button but its not working.

When I click restart button the image opacity should set to 1 and innerhtml to blank

```js
<script>
    function cards() {
        const co = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (var i in co) {
            co[i].style.opacity = 0;
        }
    }
    let i = 1;
    function choose(a) {
        document.getElementById(a).innerHTML = i++;

        win();
    }

    function win() {
        if (
            document.getElementById('1').innerHTML == '1' &&
            document.getElementById('2').innerHTML == '3' &&
            document.getElementById('3').innerHTML == '5' &&
            document.getElementById('4').innerHTML == '4' &&
            document.getElementById('5').innerHTML == '2' &&
            document.getElementById('6').innerHTML == '6'
        ) {
            document.getElementById('winn').innerHTML = 'You Won';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('winn').innerHTML = 'You Lost Try again';
        }
    }

    function erase() {
        i = 1;
        for (let j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
            document.getElementById(j.toString()).innerHTML = '';
        }
    }

    function Restart() {
        document.getElementById('img0').style.opacity = 1;
        document.getElementById('img2').style.opacity = 1;
        document.getElementById('img3').style.opacity = 1;
        document.getElementById('img4').style.opacity = 1;
        document.getElementById('img5').style.opacity = 1;
        document.getElementById('img6').style.opacity = 1;
        erase();
    }
</script>

<body onload="todays()">
    <div id="winn"></div>
    <p style="visibility: hidden;" id="hiddenvalue">X</p>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="imgbox" id="1" onclick="choose(1)" ><img id="img0" class="imgs" src="E:/GTA/to-do-app-master/todo/archons.JFIF" alt="" width="100px"></div>
        <div class="imgbox" id="2" onclick="choose(2)"><img id="img2" class="imgs" src="C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Genshin/download (1).JFIF" alt="" width="100px"></div>
        <div class="imgbox" id="3" onclick="choose(3)"><img id="img3" class="imgs" src="E:/GTA/to-do-app-master/todo/♡︎.JFIF" alt=""></div>
        <div class="imgbox" id="4" onclick="choose(4)"><img id="img4" class="imgs" src="C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Genshin/download (1).JFIF" alt="" width="100px"></div>
        <div class="imgbox" id="5" onclick="choose(5)"><img id="img5" class="imgs" src="E:/GTA/to-do-app-master/todo/archons.JFIF" alt="" width="100px"></div>
        <div class="imgbox" id="6" onclick="choose(6)"><img id="img6" class="imgs" src="E:/GTA/to-do-app-master/todo/♡︎.JFIF" alt="" ></div>
        
        <div class="btns"><button onclick="cards()">Start</button></div>
        <div class="btns"><button onclick="Restart()">Restart</button></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
function cards(){
  const co = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for( var i in co)
    {
      co[i].style.opacity= 0;          
    }
  }
```

with that:

```
function cards() {
  const co = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  for (const i of co) {
    i.style.opacity = 0;
  }
}
```

In your code `i` takes a value of `length` in the last iteration which causes the problems